# Сортировка товаров Opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Перелопатив великое множество форумов и пытаясь писать велосипед так и не нашел решения по дополнительной сортировке товаров в Opecart 2.1.0.2
Задача состоит в том чтобы товары у которых нету изображения (стоит дефолтное изображение) добавлять в конец списка. 
Пытался сделать это во фронтенд части через скрипт php но пришел к тому что это работает не коректно так как сортирует товары на каждой отдельной странице списка товаров в разделах категории.

Пришел к тому что это делается либо в модели продуктов как дополнительный параметр сортировки ко всем существующим, либо же в файле контроллера категорий, но на данный момент мои познания не настолько большие в ООП php.

Сталкивался ли кто либо с подобной задачей?

Как реализовать данного типа сортировку которая будет учитываться со всеми существующими?

Comment: кто-нибудь наверняка сталкивался. а в чём состоит ваш вопрос? уточните, пожалуйста, нажав [edit].

Comment: уточнил : Как реализовать данного типа сортировку которая будет учитываться со всеми существующими? а конкретней - товары у которых есть изображение выводятся всегда первыми + если єто возможно еще одно условие у которых указана цена

Answer (score 2):

Файл `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`, метод `getProducts()`, строка 166

```
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
}
```

заменить

```
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY IF(p.image = '', 1, 0), LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY IF(p.image = '', 1, 0), (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY IF(p.image = '', 1, 0), " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY IF(p.image = '', 1, 0), p.sort_order";
}
```

В данном примере в последнюю очередь будут выведены товары с пустым полем `image`, то есть товары без основного изображения. Если нужно отфильтровать какие-то конкретные значения условие в `IF()` потребуется изменить.

Comment: А если в нагрузку к этому условию мне то же самое нужно проделывать и с учетом отсутствия цены?

Comment: Если по цене нужно всегда сортировать, то придется добавлять в многострадальный запрос еще один параметр сортировки. Оперировать нужно этим же куском кода.

Answer (score 0):

https://microdata.pro/opencart-dev/net-v-nalichii-vnizu-spiska
Тут подробно описано тоже. А так p.image меняем на p.price с нашим условием.

И да, кэш модулей нужно обновить - иначе ничего не сработает.